# Tunning rebalance process

Tags: ignite

Can anyone share me how to config rebalanceOrder of a cache whenever rebalance process trigger?It's seem that in default, caches was rebalanced sequently by it's name

I already try to research how to tunning rebalance process of ignite, but nothing help me

Comment: anyone can help or discuss about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of threads that are taken from the system thread pool and used for rebalancing.

To get more information please follow the [link](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/data-rebalancing#configuring-rebalance-thread-pool).

IMPORTANT: The system thread pool is widely used internally by all the cache-related operations (put, get, etc.), SQL engine, and other modules. Setting the size of the rebalancing thread pool to a large value may significantly increase rebalancing performance at the cost of decreased throughput.

Comment: Tks @Konstantin: I already increased rebalance threadpool, but it's seem that the the rebalance process executed sequently, so I want to re-order this process, put rebalance process for priority cache in first

Comment: I think you can't affect the rebalance order because it will use the list of caches obtained from https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#cacheNames-- . I could be wrong, but the names there are always sorted alphabetically. You can probably name your critical caches from "A" =) You may want to consider creating/implementing this enhancement with Apache Ignite Jira, or at least ask on the developer's user list - dev@ignite.apache.org